# Differences in LayoutInflater creation

Tags: android

Whats the difference between the following LayoutInflater, which is the most effective way.

1. `LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons,null);`
2. `View view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.buttons,null);`
3. `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.buttons, mainLayout,false);`

Answer (score 0):

All 3 methods internally do the same thing. They call

```
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

But `getLayoutInflater()` will provide you the cached LayoutInflator used while creating window instead of calling `getSystemService` everytime, but not sure if it will provide any notable performance incentive, though might be a tad faster.